# Why don't we include values that make the denominator of the indefinite function zero in the domain?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

So, we can find the value of the elamus that makes the numerator and denominator zero when the simplification is done. For example:
h(x)=(x^(2)-3 x+2)/(x-1)
When we simplified this equation we get h(x)=x-2. When we try to find domain the answer does not include 1 to domain.

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbecb.png)

[And answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f85nC.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions  instead of posting pictures.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I added. Does it matter if the problem is a photo or a text?

Comment: Photos cannot be searched. So, yes, it matters.

Comment: You should never accept those values in domain which make the denominator zero as division by zero is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $f(x)=x-2 \quad(\text{for all }x\in \mathbb{R})$ is not the same as $h(x)$ in the question. I think you know that $h(x)$ cannot be defined at $x=1$ because it has $0$ in the denominator. It also has $0$ in the numerator, but you can google $0/0$ and find lots of existing discussion about this. Once you simplify $h(x)$ to get "$h(x)=x-2"$, since they are the same functions, they must have the same domain, thus $x\neq 1$. We cannot simplify and get a better domain, because when we simplify something, it should only look nicer and not be different in definition. However, it will be the case that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}h(x)=1-2=-1$, and you will learn about this when you do limits.